# Get X and Y positions of a Pixel given the HEIGHT , WIDTH and index of a pixel in FLATTENED array representing the image

Tags: image, opencl

Imagine you have this image

> [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 90]]

You flatten it into this format -

> [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 90]

Now you are given the index of Pixel 90 to be 8.
How can you find that pixel 90 is in Row 3 and column 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCL, similarly to other programming languages like C, C++, Java and so on, uses [zero based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering#Usage_in_programming_languages). So in this terms you are looking for Row 2 and Column 2.

Now to calculate which row that is we need to divide index position 8 by number of columns:

```
8 / 3 = 2
```

So in zero based indexing that is a second row.

Now to calculate which column that is we use modulo operator:

```
8 % 3 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 2D case, a point (x,y) in a rectangle with the dimensions (sx,sy) can be represented in 1D space by a linear index n as follows:

```
n = x+y*sx
```

Converting the 1D index n back to (x,y) works as follows:

```
x = n%sx
y = n/sx
```

For the 3D case, a point (x,y,z) in the a box with dimensions (sx,sy,sz) can be represented in 1D as

```
n = x+(y+z*sy)*sx
```

and converted back to (x,y,z) like this:

```
z  = n/(sx*sy);
temp = n%(sx*sy);
y = temp/sx;
x = temp%sx;
```

Note that "/" here means integer division (always rounds down the result) and "%" is the modulo operator.